# can I develop Native iOS application in HTMLH?(Be specific i am asking about Nativ iOS app)

Tags: ios, html, native

Can I develop native app in HTML5? if yes then please help me in this case.

I am specific that it should be native iOS application.

can apple will accept this application if we build in html5.

Can anybody help me to build scroll view in TOI iPad app? please provide reference

Thanks,
Gopal R

Comment: it is famous news paper "Times of india" when you type TOI on iTUnes it will give this app. Please look at Pulse i need to build such app can you let me know on which frame work they have build this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to create a native app in HTML5 for iOS. But it supports Web Apps which - if you develop specifically for the iOS - can be put on the Home Screen, have an App-Icon, use local storage, location services, ...

Hope that helps,
Christian

PS: You could check the
[Safari Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/safari/index.action)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Well, indirectly. You can create it then use [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/home/) to convert it to a native app. PhoneGap will also give you access to native APIs.

Comment: apple store will approve this appp

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can develop an HTML5/CSS3/Javascript app, then wrap it in PhoneGap to make it native and put it on the App Store (or Android Market...), as well as publish it on the web.

The added benefit is PhoneGap allows you to do additional things such as parse the iPhone contacts and access the local hardware.

It's great in combination with jQuery Mobile, but be very caution to really streamline your images, CSS, and Javascript. Performance is a major issue.

See this to learn more about Mobile Frameworks: http://www.markus-falk.com/mobile-frameworks-comparison-chart/